# Angular 4 - Can I create a form dynamically with ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to dynamically create an editable form with ngFor. Basically, a data grid and that's what I'd be using some other systems--maybe that's the way I should go, but I tried this first.

```
<form #employeeForm="ngForm">
      <tr *ngFor="let employee of newEmployees | filter:filterCriteria; let i = index" [class.active]="i == selectedRow" [attr.rowIndex]="i">
          <td class="clickable" (click)="showEmployee(i)">
             <div>{{employee.avatar}}</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <md-input-container dividerColor="accent" >
             <input mdInput placeholder="name" value={{employee.name}} name="employee-name-{{employee.id}}" [(ngModel)]="employee-name-{{employee.id}}"/>
           </md-input-container>
        </td>
       ...
        <td>
       <md-icon (click)="saveEmployeeChanges(employee.id)">save</md-icon></td>
        </tr>
</form>
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree here? If this can work, how do I access each input fields (there would be more) from within the component? And how do I get the values of every field in the row (not just the one that changed last).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem.

Have you seen this as an example: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

But what you have is an option as well. You can change this:

```
<md-icon (click)="saveEmployeeChanges(employee.id)">
```

to this:

```
<md-icon (click)="saveEmployeeChanges(employeeForm)">
```

That will pass the form and all of its associated controls to your component class.

To access the controls on the form you can use:

```
employeeForm.get('name').value;
```

You can find out more in the Angular docs here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#inspect-formcontrol-properties

Comment: Thanks @deborahk, that helps. As you wrote, I was able to get the collections of controls with employeeForm.controls after passing the form to the save method. But even googling around, I can't find the syntax to get the value of a specific control within the collection. I've tried: employeeForm.getControl("employee-name-1").value, employeeForm.get["employee-name-1"].value, employeeForm["employee-name-1"].value, employeeForm.[0].value. Just can't seem to get it.

Comment: I have a course on building Forms with Angular that covers all of this. You can find it here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-reactive-forms/table-of-contents You can sign up on the site for a free week.

Comment: I'll update my answer to respond to this question as well.

Comment: Thx again. I tried and I'm getting an error: "employeeForm.get is not a function"  saveEmployeeChanges(employeeID: string, employeeForm: FormGroup) {
    console.log("Value: ",employeeForm.get('employee-name-1').value);

    ...
}

Comment: I got it! thx @deborahk. console.log("Value: ",employeeForm.controls["employee-name-" + employeeID].value);

Comment: Yes, you can use the controls collection, but the get syntax I showed is preferred because it better handles error conditions.